# How do I make a build system for Sublime Text 2 to build msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, sublimetext

I would like to use Sublime Text 2 to build my Visual Studio 2010 solutions.

So far I have this:

Menu item Tools > Build System > New Build System...

```
{
    "cmd": ["c:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\MSBuild.exe"]
}
```

I get this error:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The
>   current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.

I'm wondering how I specify a project folder directory in the build file.

Comment: Look this post: http://blog.nikosbaxevanis.com/2013/02/07/compiling-net-projects-in-sublime-text/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I got it  to work by modifying the build system file **C:\Users\dave\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\msbuild.sublime-build** like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["c:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\MSBuild.exe"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder:${file_path}}}"
}
```

I looked at an existing build configuration that shipped with Sublime to figure it out:

> C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text
>   2\Packages\Makefile\Make.sublime-build

Answer (score 11):

There is now a full MSBuild package for Sublime Text 2 that includes syntax highlighting and completion in addition to build system integration. You can install it using Package Control or directly from https://github.com/tillig/SublimeMSBuild.

Answer (score 7):

Here is [reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) to all features of Sublime's Build System.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is because you did not specify what you wanted to build. See the [MSBuild Command Line Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx). At the very least you need to specify a project file:

```
MSBuild MySolution.sln
MSBuild MyProject.csproj
MSBUild MyMSBuildScript.proj
```

Comment: Bryan, thanks for the answer. msbuild will build a solution or project if there is only one in the folder msbuild is invoked from. I got it to work as described in my answer.