# Error6 while trying to use sublime text to msbuild

Tags: msbuild, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I'm trying to use msbuild with my sublime project.  I created the build file [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646776/how-do-i-make-a-build-system-for-sublime-text-2-to-build-msbuild) and the following is my project file

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/W/MyOrg/MyApp",
                        "folder_exclude_patterns": ["_ReSharper.*", "bin", "obj"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I select the msbuild40 build system and hit `Build` and get the output:

```
[Error 6] The handle is invalid
[Finished]
```

I'm not even sure if this is a python or an msbuild error. Which is it, how can I fix it, and whats a good way to troubleshoot this sort of stuff in the future?

#### Update

I tried updating my project to the following and using that build and still no dice

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/W/MyOrg/MyApp",
            "folder_exclude_patterns": ["_ReSharper.*", "bin", "obj"]
        }
    ],
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "msbuild",
            "cmd": ["c:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\MSBuild.exe", "w:\\MyOrg\\MyApp\\MyApp.sln"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out that this happens whenever you start sublime from command line ( I was starting it via a powershell alias).

You can fix this by using a batch file and [the START command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html). I created sublime_text.bat:

```
START "Sublime Text 2"  "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" %*
```

and set my powershell alias to that bat file. Now everything works.

Comment: That's mighty annoying. I _live_ in the command line so I never start ST2 (or anything else) except from the CLI. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: Thank you veeeeery much! This solved a problem I had with using SublimeREPL: https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/271

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with ST3's subl.exe. I could only get it to work with sublime_text.exe. :(