# The handle is invalid

Tags: sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2. Whenever I start Sublime Text from the command line, and run the code I am working, I always get:

```
[Error 6] The handle is invalid
```

But when I start Sublime from "windows + r", everything goes as it should. Why?

I am using portable version of Sublime and my working dir is D (for I do not own the computer I am using).

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: @Blender Here's the error msg:
[Error 6] The handle is invalid
[cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'D:\\Dropbox\\Workspace\\projectEuler.net\\even_fibonacci_number.py']]
[dir:  D:\Dropbox\Workspace\projectEuler.net]
[path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\Scripts;D:\Dropbox\Sublime Text 2.0.1;D:\Dropbox\Console2]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error6 while trying to use sublime text to msbuild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438508/error6-while-trying-to-use-sublime-text-to-msbuild) (which also has a useful answer)

Answer (score 0):

I start mine with from git bash with the alias 

`alias subl="start sublime_text.exe"` 
with double-quotes and it works perfectly.

If I do it any other way it doesn't work quite right and I get the same error as above in the console of Sublime Text 2.