# How to build c++ code outside of microsoft visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sublimetext3

(Noob here, so apologies for the very basic question). Currently I mostly use Sublime Text for editing code. However to compile I alt-tab to MSVC and compile there and then alt-tab again to a file browser and launch my .exe file. I am looking for a way to optimise this and not having to alt-tab all the time.

So first question is: Is there way to make Sublime Text compile a MSVC C++ project ? I know you can press Ctrl-B, but then you have to know how to set-up all the compiler options link all the libraries (and this was a total nightmare for me to do in MSVC, so preferrably I do not have to do this again for some other compiler).

Second question is: Once the .exe is compiled, is there way to make Sublime launch the .exe (now I have to look it up in my file browser each time, which is a huge pain).

Comment: If you have a MS solution already this may help with question 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646776/how-do-i-make-a-build-system-for-sublime-text-2-to-build-msbuild

Comment: Also it would be nice to consider alternatives like [eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) .

Comment: No eclipse or other IDE's are not really option for me as they do not provide the text editing options that Sublime Text 3 provides (such as vim mode, multiple cursors, all my own scripts and snippets, and so on and so forth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For once I do have a solution !

Here it is :

- You have to be able to create shortcuts in ST to launch an external app [I've tried this in ST3](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ExternalTools)
- You probably have Visual Studio solution at this point, so you need to create a shortcut to start MSBuild.exe
- Create a shortcut to start your .exe

I found an old script that uses MSBuild to build an old solution like that :

```
%PATH_TO_MSBUILD%\MSBuild.exe %SLN_ABSOLUTE_PATH% /t:Clean /t:%TARGET% /p:Configuration=%MODE_COMPILATION%
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild) to trigger a build using your Visual Studio project file. See the examples in the official documentation, e.g.:

```
MSBuild.exe MyProj.proj -property:Configuration=Debug
```

Note that you may have to initialize your environment beforehand. See [Use the MSVC toolset from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line) for that, e.g. by calling `vcvarsall.bat` etc.